# How to create dynamic itab from the existing one?

Tags: dynamic, abap, internal-tables

I have following internal table:

```
VBELN   POSNR   ELEMENT VALUE

4711    10      E1      12      
4711    10      E2      23
```

Is there any possibility in ABAP (Framework, Class, etc), so I can fast create a new internal table at runtime which would look like this:

```
VBELN   POSNR   E1  E2

4711    10      12  23
```

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks and BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are the ABAP Runtime Type Services (RTTS) or [ABAP Runtime Type Creation (RTTC)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_pgl.htm).

```
DATA(vbeln_descriptor) = CAST cl_abap_datadescr( cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'VBELN' ) ).
DATA(posnr_descriptor) = CAST cl_abap_datadescr( cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'POSNR' ) ).
DATA(components) = VALUE abap_component_tab( ( name = 'VBELN'
                                               type = vbeln_descriptor )
                                             ( name = 'POSNR'
                                               type = posnr_descriptor ) ).

DATA(value_descriptor) = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'VALUE' ).
LOOP AT vbeln_rows INTO DATA(vbeln_row).
  INSERT VALUE #( 
      name = vbeln_row-element
      type = value_descriptor )
    INTO TABLE components.
ENDLOOP.

DATA(row_descriptor) = cl_abap_structdescr=>get( components ).
DATA(table_descriptor) = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( row_descriptor ).

DATA itab TYPE REF TO data.
CREATE DATA itab TYPE HANDLE table_descriptor.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast respone, Florian!
One small question. I get a syntax error in the line 4 saying "the type of "VBELN_DEXCRIPTOR" is not convertable in the type of "TYPE".

Did you have the same issue?

Comment: Only put it together in the text editor, so there may be minor syntax errors. But it works. Done this several times. Added a `CAST` in lines 1 and 2 to fix the issue you mention.

Comment: Note that I didn't know the Data Dictionary Data Element behind the `VALUE` column. You may want to exchange this with the data element's real name.

Comment: Thanks again, Florian. I've just checked RTTC, it really powerful framework.
I'm still learning and hope it's ok if I ask one small question: now I get the same error as before but in the line 12, but I guess I cannot CAST there, or?
I maked the following change in the line 8:
DATA(value_descriptor) = CAST cl_abap_typedescr( cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'VALUE' ) ).
But still get the error..

Comment: @dyz it could be a warning not an error, because the cast is useless when the casted type is the same as the original result type!

Comment: Check what the column TYPE in the COMPONENTS table expects and cast to that. I guess it’s a DATA or ELEMENT descriptor. Those classes form a hierarchy. Some methods, especially the describe_by ones reside on the top class and therefore also return their result as that topmost general class. In truth however the returned instances will always be something much more specific and can be safely casted. I consider this a design flaw of the hierarchy. Clean object orientation doesn’t require casting.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the Info, Florian! It helped me a lot and I found out how to do this now!